# Android emulator, Google API 7, only small part of emulator desktop is displayed

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My android emulator doesn`t show the whole picture. I mean, it displays only a small part of desktop.
I got this problem after I installed Google API 7. I attached 2 images: the first one contains the problem. The second one is ok.
How to decrease display scale to see the whole android desktop?

Problem image (Android API 7 + google API):
[image: Problem image]
OK image (Android API 7):
[image: OK image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new emulator with
HVGA skin or the skin which you want.
from the area which is highlighted in image

[image: Emulator Image]